# seq command with && operator wont work

Tags: command-line

I'm trying to make a for loop in bash where I make a beep of a particular frequency than is incremented until it reaches 500, then goes back down to 1.
I'm using the "seq" command for this but I ran into a bit of a roadblock, I can't use the "&&" operator on seq! Whenever I run it, it increments to 500, but it doesn't go back down again. For example, if I run

```
for i in $( seq 1 10 && seq 10 1 );
do
    echo $i
done
```

It outputs

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

And it doesn't go back down. And it's not just the for loops, I've tried it in the terminal with just the two seq commands and it still wont work. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: why not use 2 for loops?

Comment: @Tim I tried that. The output is the same.

Comment: Yeah, the issue is 10 1 doesn't count down. Go for {1..10} and then {10..1}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to give the increment as negative number i.e. in your case `-1`.

For example:

```
$ seq 1 5 && seq 5 -1 1
1
2
3
4
5
5
4
3
2
1
```

Here `seq 5 -1 1` takes the format `seq FIRST INCREMENT LAST`.

Furthermore, if you want every alternate numbers from 10 to 0:

```
$ seq 10 -2 0
10
8
6
4
2
0
```

Check `man seq` to get more idea.